# How to get the dimensions of a CFAttributedStringRef given its string and attributes?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, core-text, core-foundation

Given a `CFAttributedStringRef` pointer, the `CFStringRef` and all the attributes such as the `CTFont` or `CTParagraphStyleRef` and what not, how do I find out the minimum dimension required for my CGContextRef?

Here's some code:

```
// create one attribute
CFArrayRef fontDescriptors = CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL((__bridge CFURLRef)urlToFontFile);
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(fontDescriptors, 0), 40, NULL);
// create a dictionary for the attributes
CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName };
CFTypeRef values[] = { font };
CFDictionaryRef attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**)&keys,
                                                (const void**)&values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]),
                                                &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
// create my string
CFStringRef textString = CFSTR("Hello World!");
// finally, create my attributed string
CFAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, textString, attributes);

// now how do I get the width and height of my attributed string?
```

Comment: See [CoreText. How Do I Calculate the Bounding Box of an Attributed String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988498/coretext-how-do-i-calculate-the-bounding-box-of-an-attributed-string)